Spectral Descomposition - Outer Product
I was work with the spectral decomposition  $X^{T}X = U\Lambda U^{T}$, where $X$ is an $n×p$ model matrix with $rk(X) = p $ using in the linear regression $Y = X\beta +\epsilon$, $U$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $X^{T}X$. I can do this decomposition because $X^{T}X$ is symmetric.I know that
$$X^{T}X=\sum_{i=1}^{p}x_{i}x_{i}^{T}$$
and
$$U\Lambda U^{T} =\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}u_{i}u_{i}^{T}$$
Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{p}x_{i}x_{i}^{T} =\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}u_{i}u_{i}^{T}$$
My question if I can affirm that $x_{i}x_{i}^{T} = \lambda_{i}u_{i}u_{i}^{T}$. I'm not sure about this statement.

No.
Let $x_1 = (1,1)^T$, $x_2=(1,-1)^T.$
$$XX^T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}=diag(2,2)$$
But we can choose $u_i=e_i$ and $u_iu_i^T$ is diagonal but $x_1x_1^T$ is not diagonal.
